# cmd - sed - beginner

Tags: sed, cmd

I'm learning sed and i typed this command into cmd prompt of xp.

```
# echo "All day and all night" | sed 's/day/night/'.
```

What does `|` do?

And, I'm getting this weird error if I type this command into 
`c:\wamp\www\work\delete\test`. The command keeps repeating forever.
But If I go one level up or wherever, then it executes once.

Comment: is there a program named "echo" or "sed" in that directory?

Comment: that was exactly it... but not sure how that would make it loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is called a *pipe* and  its effect is to send the output of the first command to the second command.

[Here is an interesting reading](http://commandwindows.com/command1.htm) about it for you, and [another one](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx) from microsoft